# How do I make a tab active with Barik theme?

Tags: theming

Should I do it in css or jquery? Not sure why it's not something done by default.

Comment: What do you mean by Tab Active ? Are you using Quick Tabs ? Can you post a screenshot which gives more information ?

Comment: Hi Anil, I am wanting the tab to be red when it is on the page. Like if I was on Spring 2014, then that tab is red while the other looks the same. http://d.pr/i/M9Sl